# Weak harnack type inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have reached a lemma which I do not have any reference and hint for it.

> Assume $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R^N} $ is smooth bounded domain and 
>   let $u$ be a positive distributional supersolution to 
>   \begin{cases} \Delta^2 u = 0 \hspace{.3cm} in \hspace{.1cm} Ω \\
>  u =-\Delta u= 0 \hspace{.3cm} on \hspace{.1cm} ∂Ω \end{cases}
>   then for any $B_R(x_0) ⊂⊂ Ω $, there exists a positive constant $C = C(θ, ρ, q,R)$ , $0 <q< \dfrac{N}{ N−2}$ , $0 <θ<ρ< 1$ , such that
>
> $$||u||_{L^q(B_{ρR}(x_0))}  \leq C  \hspace{.2cm} ess \inf_{B_{θR}(x_0)}u$$

I need a reference or hint. or any help to proof it. so thanks. I think I must use an appropriate test function in the definition of supersolution